# Laravel Sentry Update the User

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I have a problem with Sentry. The problem is probably that under  $user = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findById($id);it is not only finding one user, but many users. Thus it cannot recognize the method user->save.

How can I solve this problem?

I am trying to build a form to edit my user details.

Thank you.

My form looks like this:

```
 {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'profile/useredit')) }}

                                            {{ Form::text('address',null) }}
                                            <br>
                                            {{Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-default'))}}
                                        {{ Form::close() }}



/**
         * Edit the user profile under profile/user
         *
         * @return View
         */
        public function postUseredit(){
            try {
            $id= Session::get(Config::get('sentry::sentry.session.user')); 
            // Get the user information
            $user = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findById($id);
        } catch (UserNotFoundException $e) {
            // Prepare the error message

            $error = Lang::get('users/message.user_not_found', compact('id'));

            // Redirect to the user management page
            return Redirect::route('users')->with('error', $error);
        }


        try {
            // Update the user
            $user->first_name  = Input::get('first_name');
            $user->last_name   = Input::get('last_name');
            $user->email       = Input::get('email');
            $user->dob   = Input::get('dob');
            $user->bio   = Input::get('bio');
            $user->gender   = Input::get('gender');
            $user->country   = Input::get('country');
            $user->state   = Input::get('state');
            $user->city   = Input::get('city');
            $user->address   = Input::get('address');
            $user->postal   = Input::get('postal');
            $user->activated   = Input::get('activate')?1:0;


/*
            // is new image uploaded?
            if ($file = Input::file('pic'))
            {
                $fileName        = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $extension       = $file->getClientOriginalExtension() ?: 'png';
                $folderName      = '/uploads/users/';
                $destinationPath = public_path() . $folderName;
                $safeName        = str_random(10).'.'.$extension;
                $file->move($destinationPath, $safeName);

                //delete old pic if exists
                if(File::exists(public_path() . $folderName.$user->pic))
                {
                    File::delete(public_path() . $folderName.$user->pic);
                }

                //save new file path into db
                $user->pic   = $safeName;

            }

            */
/*
            // Get the current user groups
            $userGroups = $user->groups()->lists('group_id', 'group_id');

            // Get the selected groups
            $selectedGroups = Input::get('groups', array());

            // Groups comparison between the groups the user currently
            // have and the groups the user wish to have.
            $groupsToAdd    = array_diff($selectedGroups, $userGroups);
            $groupsToRemove = array_diff($userGroups, $selectedGroups);

            // Assign the user to groups
            foreach ($groupsToAdd as $groupId) {
                $group = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findById($groupId);

                $user->addGroup($group);
            }

            // Remove the user from groups
            foreach ($groupsToRemove as $groupId) {
                $group = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findById($groupId);

                $user->removeGroup($group);
            }
*/
            // Was the user updated?
            if ($user->save()) {
                // Prepare the success message
                $success = Lang::get('users/message.success.update');

                // Redirect to the user page
                return Redirect::route('profile/user', $id)->with('success', $success);
            }

            // Prepare the error message
            $error = Lang::get('users/message.error.update');
        } catch (LoginRequiredException $e) {
            $error = Lang::get('users/message.user_login_required');
        }

        // Redirect to the user page
        return Redirect::route('profile/user', $id)->withInput()->with('error', $error);
    }
```

Comment: Error is Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$user = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findById($id);
```

try this

```
$user = Sentry::findUserById($id);
```